# Chrome - type=file drag and drop

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a weird situation. One of my users is using functionality of Chrome (current version, 49, 50), that he drags and drops a file from his folder on local computer to **normal** input type=file button in a form on the webpage. Once again, let me stress it even more, its **normal html input**, no fancy javascript, no drag&drop events and handlers, nothing like this. It just takes the name of the dragged file and puts it into the input field, as like he selected it via "normal" way, opening the file select window, locating file on harddrive, selecting the file and confirming.
  In some specific situation, this stops working (while doing some edits in the page via javascript / ajax), and I need to "reenable" it. 
  But, and that is my question, I haven't found any documentation of this "feature" in Google Chrome (or maybe some other browsers as well, I don't know). Why it works, how it works, how it should work and what to do if it stops working :) Does anyone has any experience with this ? The only way how to "fix" it now is to reload the page. I'd love to solve it ... :)

EDIT 1 : I just did a quick test, it works and bugs the same way in Firefox on Win. It doesn't show any error in dev console or any message, it just doesn't add the file as expected.

Comment: I don't know about Chrome in particular, but in general, on OS X, this is pretty normal stuff. Dragging and dropping is part of the OS' vocabulary, and dragging a file onto a file input selector as a shorthand move has worked roughly since forever...

Comment: Yeah, might be the same for other browsers on Win as well, I haven't use before, but as I programmed some other drag and drop uploads (in different area of the page), some users thought this is the same and start drag and dropping files onto normal file input box. And it worked :) But as I said, in some rare occasions, it stops working, and I wonder if its just "plain bug" of the browser or if there is something I can call on my side to "fix it", some javascript refresh or whatever.

Comment: I just did a quick test, it works and bugs the same way in Firefox on Win, so there might be something in common (except Win :) )

Answer (score 0):

I've found it. The previous discussion with deceze pointed me to test the javascripts I have on the page, that do not "interfere" with the input type=file ... they weren't any such scripts, but I've found that after doubleclick on the table (that I'm using for editing) this script is being called

```
$(document).bind('drop dragover', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

and there wasn't any unbind action when table is saved ... this caused the drag and drop everywhere on the page to stop working after the edit.